# Javascriptでフォーム調整プログラム（その他を選択時に追加の選択事項を表示、選択させる）を書きたいです

Tags: javascript, html, html5, form

プログラムを最近独学で始めたのですが、インターネットで調べながらやってみたい動作が
なかなか上手く動作しません。

下のプログラム単体では動くのですが、
`elements`、`len`、`sele_val`を『`elements1`、`elements2`、`elements3`』といった形で増やす　
と動作しなくなってしまいます。

動かしたいプログラムとして、
・『その他』を選択した時のみ、『その他詳細』を選択できるようにしたい。
・同様の動作が１つのフォームで複数箇所あるため、まとめて書きたい
なのですが、どうやってもうまく動きません。

下記、一つだけ書くと動くコードになります。
何卒、ご指導のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

```
function controlselect() {
    let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("disselect");
    let len = elements.length;
    var sele_val = document.getElementById("other").value;
    if(sele_val === "その他") {
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++){
            elements.item(i).removeAttribute("disabled");
        }
    }else {
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++){
            elements.item(i).setAttribute("disabled", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

次のような形で実現できないでしょうか:

```js
// 引数で要素のグループを指定する
function controlselect(target) {
  let elements = target.getElementsByClassName("disselect");
  let len = elements.length;
  // id は使えないので class に変更する
  var sele_val = target.getElementsByClassName("other")[0].value;
  if (sele_val === "その他") {
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      elements.item(i).removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      elements.item(i).setAttribute("disabled", true);
    }
  }
}
```

---

実装例:

```js
function controlselect(target) {
  let elements = target.getElementsByClassName("disselect");
  let len = elements.length;
  var sele_val = target.getElementsByClassName("other")[0].value;
  if (sele_val === "その他") {
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      elements.item(i).removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      elements.item(i).setAttribute("disabled", true);
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const targets = ["elements1", "elements2", "elements3"];
  for (let t of targets) {
    const div = document.getElementById(t);
    div
      .getElementsByClassName("other")[0]
      .addEventListener("change", () => controlselect(div));
    controlselect(div);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="elements1">
      <div>
        <select class="other">
          <option value="a">A</option>
          <option value="b">B</option>
          <option value="その他">OTHER</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" class="disselect" />
        <input type="text" class="disselect" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="elements2">
      <div>
        <select class="other">
          <option value="a">A</option>
          <option value="b">B</option>
          <option value="その他">OTHER</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" class="disselect" />
        <input type="text" class="disselect" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="elements3">
      <div>
        <select class="other">
          <option value="a">A</option>
          <option value="b">B</option>
          <option value="その他">OTHER</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" class="disselect" />
        <input type="text" class="disselect" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: お返事が遅くなり、大変申し訳ございません。
試してみたところ、イメージどおりの動作しました。
まだまだわからないことばかりで、勉強する身ですがKazuyukiさんのように教える立場までの技術をつけれるようがんばります。
ありがとうございました！